# JMockit: any way to log calls made to Mocks

Tags: java, jmockit

Is there some way to output/log calls made to mocks in JMockit?

I've got a Verification block that is failing due to a missing invocation with a specific set of parameters.  I would like to know/see if any invocations of the mocked method were made, and if so, with what parameters.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Tried to use a debugger?

Comment: @Andy - looking to be able to log it to the screen to view all the calls instead of manually stepping through using a debugger.